# Diagonalize a matrix using singular value decomposition

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Suppose I have a product $A^{T}MA,$ where $A$ and $M$ are $n\times k$ and $%
n\times n$ full rank matrices. $A^{T}MA$ is assumed to be diagonal matrix
with different entries. I want to find a way to get $A$ that diagnolize $%
A^{T}MA.$ For a given matrix $M$ and a preliminary $\hat{A},$ I understand
that one way is to use eigenvalues and eigenvectors, i.e., let $\hat{A}^{T}M%
\hat{A}=PDP^{-1},$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix, the by letting $A=\hat{A}%
P^{-1},$ then $A^{T}MA=P^{-1}\hat{A}^{T}M\hat{A}P^{-1}=P^{-1}PDP^{-1}P=D.$
However, for the eigenvectors and eigenvaluels, it may introduce complex
numbers instead of real number. Another way is to use singular value
decomposition $\hat{A}^{T}M\hat{A}=UDV,$ then the question is how to define $A$ based on the above singular value decomposition to satisfy $A^{T}MA$ being a diagonal matrix $D.$ Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify the question: you say that $A^TMA$ is diagonal, and then you want to find a matrix that diagonalizes it. You could just use the identity!

Comment: Yes, $A$ is a unknown matrix, but I can find some preliminary matrix, $M$ is known. $A^TMA$ is  assumed to be diagonal matrix.